# Website transferred in need of redirect

Tags: redirect, dns, transfer

really need help just transferrred a website.

I have the support forum setup on the new website as.

```
www.example.com/support
```

their existing support address was

```
www.support.example.com
```

How do i setup a redirect for this to redirect anyone the enters www.support.example.com to www.example.com/support

Comment: thanks for the reply no using plesk with media temple

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `meta` tag to the page which represents `www.support.example.com` and it will redirect to your new URL. Remember to change the URL within the `meta` tag to that of your new one.

> ```
> <html><head>
> <title>Title</title>
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.example.com/support"> 
> </head>
> <body>   <p> bla bla bla.. </p>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```